libnvidia-encode1 has no installation candidate
Just trying to download the requirements to run Davinci Resolve via this article on Ubuntu 23.10. Resolve boots, but I doesn't recognize my GPU (RTX3060TI). I have NVIDIA drivers installed already for AI-related things, so I'm not sure what the issue is with Resolve. Anyway, I keep getting "no installation candidate" when I try to run any of the GPU driver installs.
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-encode1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libnvidia-encode1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libnvidia-encode1' has no installation candidate

The other NVIDIA driver install gives the same kind of error
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver nvidia-opencl-icd libcuda1 libglu1-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-opencl-icd is a virtual package provided by:
  libnvidia-compute-550-server 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.23.10.3
  libnvidia-compute-550 550.67-0ubuntu1.23.10.2
  libnvidia-compute-545 545.29.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.2
  libnvidia-compute-535-server 535.161.08-0ubuntu2.23.10.1
  libnvidia-compute-535 535.171.04-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
  libnvidia-compute-470-server 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
  libnvidia-compute-470 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
You should explicitly select one to install.

Package libcuda1 is a virtual package provided by:
  libnvidia-compute-470-server 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 (= 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)
  libnvidia-compute-470 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 (= 470.239.06-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver
E: Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libcuda1' has no installation candidate


If you run apt policy libnvidia-encode1 nvidia-opencl-icd the results of the command will clearly show that these packages are not in the default Ubuntu 23.10 repositories,  so the tutorial is no good.
